# Laravel 5.0 Consultas WhereIn

Tags: php, laravel, sql

Buenas a todos

Tengo el siguiente problema: desde la url recogo un **id** con el que hago una consulta de la que saco un array. Con este array realizo otra consulta para sacar los datos que necesito en otra tabla. El problema me viene a la hora de mostrar los datos en la vista solo me devuelve un valor, mientras que al hacer un echo desde el foreach del controlador me muestra todos los valores.

**Controlador**

```
public function mostrarFacturas($id){
    $tienes = Tiene::where('idrc',$id)->select('idfactura')->get();     

    foreach ($tienes as $tiene => $valor) {
        $facturas = Factura::select('id' ,'nfactura', 'importe' ,'fecha')
        ->whereIn('id' , [$valor->idfactura])->get();
        echo $facturas;
        dd($facturas);
    }
    return view('rc.showFacturas' , [
        'tienes' => $tienes,
        'facturas' => $facturas ]);
}
```

**Contenido plantilla**

```
    @extends('layouts.menuarea') 
    @section('content')

   @foreach($facturas as $factura)
   {{$factura}}
   @endforeach
   @stop
```

[image: Contenido echo]

[image: Vista]

Por otro lado si realizo un **dd($facturas)** desde el foreach solo recibo un valor.[image: dd]

Ademas no estoy seguro de estar utilizando el whereIn de forma correcta. agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner los modelos de Tiene y de Factura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo solo el código que has puesto, en el controlador estas machacando el valor de `$facturas` en cada ciclo del `foreach`

```
public function mostrarFacturas($id){
    $tienes = Tiene::where('idrc',$id)->select('idfactura')->get();     

    foreach ($tienes as $tiene => $valor) {
        //aqui se reasigna un vuevo valor en cada ciclo
        $facturas = Factura::select('id' ,'nfactura', 'importe' ,'fecha')
            ->whereIn('id' , [$valor->idfactura])->get();
        echo $facturas;
    }
    return view('rc.showFacturas' , [
        'tienes' => $tienes,
        'facturas' => $facturas ]);
}
```

La forma mas fácil de corregirlo sería estableciendo `$facturas` como un array

Es decir:

```
public function mostrarFacturas($id){
    $tienes = Tiene::where('idrc',$id)->select('idfactura')->get();     

    foreach ($tienes as $tiene => $valor) {
        //indicamos que se almacene en un array con los []
        $facturas[] = Factura::select('id' ,'nfactura', 'importe' ,'fecha')
            ->whereIn('id' , [$valor->idfactura])->get();
        //echo $facturas;
    }
    return view('rc.showFacturas' , [
        'tienes' => $tienes,
        'facturas' => $facturas ]);
}
```

Por otro lado si defines las relaciones en los modelos es posible que este código se simplifique utilizando los métodos que eloquent nos provee.

Podría revisar la documentación para adaptar sus modelos, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. los modelos de las relaciones los utilizo en otras tablas, llevo poco con laravel y para esta tabla no he sido capaz de utilizarlo ya que es una tabla generada por una relacion N:M y se me descontrolaban los datos.